# Transform a fitted exponential curve in an exponetial distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-function, exponential-distribution

I am not a mathematician, but I want to do this:

Let us suppose to have some data exponential distributed in an interval $[a,b]$, I want to find the exponential distribution of this data and the mean.
I polyfitted the data with NumPy in order to get two parameters, let us call $c_0$ and $c_1$.

Now the curve that describes the data is $f_1(x) = e^{c_1}*e^{c_0x}$.
The data grow increasing x, while in the exponential distribution, there is decay, so I consider $f_1(-x)$.
Now I have $f_2(x) = e^{c_1}*e^{-c_0x}$.

To be a distribution, I need that the integral $\int_{a}^{b} f_2(x) \,dx=1$. So I divide the function for this integral.
Now I have the $f_3= \frac{f_2}{\int_{a}^{b} f_2(x) \,dx}$.
I computed the integral in Wolfram Alpha and I tried to apply a little bit of algebra to derive a form like $ f_3 = \lambda*e^{-\lambda x}$ in order to get the mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, but I didn't succeed.
The idea is to get the mean of the data knowing that they are exponentially distributed. To do this I tried to get an exponential distribution to describe my data without success

Can someone help?

Comment: This is not clear at all and almost impossible to read

Comment: I dunno how to use the math notation

Comment: Try to add graphs to explain what you have done and what you want to do.

Comment: I used the math notation, if it is not clear, I can add plots, but I think they are not useful because here is a problem of getting a certain formula, assuming that the idea is correct of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you have done and you want to do. But here's some remarks:

1. You have somehow obtained the function $f_2(x) = e^{c_1}e^{-c_0 x}$. You say you want this because it is exponential: problem is that it is not. We may want to compute $c_1$ such that the resuting function is the exponential distribution (which is for $c_1 = \log c_0$)
2. an exponential distribution has support $[0,\infty)$ which means that if you rstrict to $[a,b]$ the resulting distribution is not exponentially distributed
3. I don't understnd why you want so desperately to have an exponential: is it just because you know an easy way to say what its mean is? We can simpy compute the mean of you r.v. distributed according to your $f_3$ by using the definition of mean: assume $X$ has density given by $f_3$ then its mean is:
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[X] := \int_{a}^{b} xf_3(x) dx
   $$

Comment: I have my data  (x,y) that are exponentially distributed. I used polyfit in python on this curve in this way: numpy.polyfit(x, numpy.log(y), 1). In this way, you get two parameters $c_0$ and $c_1$. The function $f_2$ is the exponential curve that fits my data.

Comment: @Carl Premise: exponential functions and exponential distributions are two different things. If the fitted curve is an exponential with a positive sign, why do you change it to $-x$? If $f_1$ is the function that approximate best your data, changing it to $f_2$ is not correct. As stated in remark 3, to compute the mean of $f_1$ (after normalizing it to get a proper distribution), just use the definition of mean I provided

Comment: I consider $f(-x)$ to make the shape of the exponential curve of my data similar to the shape of the exponential distribution to derive the mean. But you are right, I had overcomplicated things. At this point, I can find the average of the function without considering the distribution. So I will compute $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} f_1(x) \,dx$. If make it sense, I will flag your answer as the best. Let me know.

Comment: If they don't have to be distributions , then yes you are correct